# Period usage in Figures and Table captions

Tags: technical, periods

In technical writing I see that some templates do no use a period after Figure number. For eg I see "Fig 1 Machine Schematic" instead of "Fig 1. Machine Schematic". I see the latter being the right usage rather than the former. I would like to know what is the right usage?

Comment: Why would you expect the period _after_ the number? Shouldn't it be _after_ "fig" as that is the word that is shortened?

Comment: @KillingTime I think so too, but something after the number is also normal

Comment: There is no right way. This is a matter of opinion or convention. It is for that that reason that I have regretfully voted to close a sensible question. All that may be confidently advised is that the same style should apply throughout an article or publication.

Comment: We've had plenty of questions that similarly are answered by the opinion of one or more style guides. Perhaps it could be better worded as "what's the correct punctuation settings figure numbering" but I'm voting to reopen anyway. It might well be on topic at writers.se; I know technical writing is covered there, if quite rarely

Answer (score 1):

The usage I'm most familiar with is "Fig. 1: a figure" or "Figure 1: a figure" with a colon introducing the caption proper. Note the full stop/period used when "Figure" is abbreviated.

This is the output produced by many journal templates I've used (their LaTeX templates, which take care of the figure numbering style automatically). Figure captions are a little odd in that they're not usually full sentences, at least if fairly short; even in long captions the first sentence often isn't.
This makes it hard to apply normal punctuation rules.

Styles vary but I can't immediately recall seeing the style you disagree with. I've seen a dash. I've seen a different font. I've seen a line break or large space, especially with a style that uses boxed figures and puts "figure *n*" in the frame of the box but keeps the caption underneath or adjacent.

Comment: Without a separator after a Figure or a change in font style it looks like a continuous sentence. I am seeing this in the datasheets of my company and I am thinking of suggesting to change the styling.